# Good RegExp for iran phone number

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need a good and best **RegExp** for validate Iranian phone number like this:

0903*******

0918*******

in this RegExp should check the user should **just start phone number with 0** not other things like area code (+98)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
("^[0][9][0-9][0-9]{8,8}$")
```

Using case in js:

```
const IsValidPhone = (val) => {
  let regex = new RegExp("^[0][9][0-9][0-9]{8,8}$").test(val);
  return regex;
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that the pattern can be shortened to `^09\d{9}$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```js
/^(09)[0-9]{9,9}$/gu
```

Comment: The group in `(09)` is unnecessary, `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]` and `{9,9}` can be condensed to `{9}`. And about `/gu` you don't expect/handle any unicode characters and you match only a single occurance, the entire string. So `/^09\d{9}$/`